# Continously run testng in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, automated-tests, testng

I've inherited a java testing application written in java/eclipse/testng, I'm a .net developer. I can run the test suite just fine, but I'm having difficulty in figuring out how to rerun the tests immediately after the suite has run. Does anyone have anything to point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: http://infinitest.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

rerun the tests? what do you mean by here?

Do you want to run the multiple suites one after the other?

if so

```
<suite name="automated suites">
  <suite-files>
    <suite-file path="suitea.xml" />
    <suite-file path="suiteb.xml" />
    ...
  </suite-files>
</suite>
```

or the same suite?

```
<suite name="automated suites">
      <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="suitea.xml" />
        <suite-file path="suitea.xml" />
        ...
      </suite-files>
    </suite>
```